# get original width and height of the product image in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

i have an issue i want to display the image product with the original size without resize it in the product.php file

```
$this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height'));
```

then i want add $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width') with another statement to get the original size to change it in a specific case

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient (be sure to change the conditions

```
$this->data['thumb'] = HTTP_SERVER . 'image/' . $product_info['image'];
if(.. CONDITIONS HERE FOR RESIZED ..) {
    $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height'));
}
```